# Rolling back 2 stored procedures if the second stored procedure did not insert any rows

Tags: json, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, triggers

The following stored procedure `INSERT1` works perfectly fine. It triggers stored procedure `INSERT2` based on data_type_id and inserts data into a separate table. But I want to edit this stored procedure `INSERT1` (or `INSERT2`) such that, if NO rows are inserted into `TABLE2` via `INSERT2`, then I want to roll back `INSERT1`. I was thinking maybe using something like

```sql
Set @rows_affected = @@rowcount
         
if ((@rows_affected = 0))
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

But I'm not sure how to edit the procedure such that, if NO rows are inserted via stored procedure `INSERT2`, then roll back both stored procedures `INSERT1` & `INSERT2`.

```sql
Create PROCEDURE INSERT1 (
    @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int
    declare @submission_id varchar(32)
    declare @dataset_id varchar(32)
    declare @json varchar(max) 
    DECLARE @v_data_type_id varchar(50)

    Set @v_data_type_id = (SELECT  data_type_id
    FROM OPENJSON (@JsonData, N'$')
    WITH (data_type_id varchar(32) '$.dataTypeId'))

    set @json = @JsonData

    Begin TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (
        submission_id,
        data_set_id,
        data_type_id, 
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@json, N'$') WITH (
        submission_id varchar(32) N'$.submissionId',
        data_set_id varchar(32) N'$.dataSetId',
        data_type_id varchar(50) N'$.dataTypeId',
    ) 

    if ((@v_data_type_id = '1'))
    BEGIN 
        exec [dbo].[INSERT2] @json  
  
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                RETURN
            END
        END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Here's the INSERT2 script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT2 (
    @Json_PMU1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int
    DECLARE @submission_id varchar(32)
    DECLARE @dataset_id varchar(32)

SELECT  @submission_id = submission_id,
        @dataset_id = data_set_id
from openjson(@Json_PMU1, N'$')
with (
submission_id varchar(32) N'$.submissionId',
data_set_id varchar(32) N'$.dataSetId'
)

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (
        name,
        contact_number,
        submission_id,
        data_set_id
)
select  Name as name,
        contactNumber as contact_number,
        @submission_id as submission_id, 
        @dataset_id as data_set_id
        
--into TABLE2

from openjson (@Json_PMU1, '$.data.Table2')
with (
    Name varchar(255) ,
    contactNumber char(11) 
)
SELECT @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN (@err)
    
    
    
END
```

Comment: What aren't you sure about here?

Comment: @Larnu How to edit the stored procedure such that if INSERT2 inserts 0 rows then roll back the entire procedure, INSERT1 & INSERT2

Comment: Insert `begin tran` before the insert, and that conditional rollback after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't just rollback.  You should throw an exception in INSERT2, then rollback, then send the exception to the client to inform the client that the requested process did not occur.  EG

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE INSERT1 ( @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX) )
AS
  BEGIN
  SET XACT_ABORT ON
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @err int
    declare @submission_id varchar(32)
    declare @dataset_id varchar(32)
    declare @json varchar(max) 
    DECLARE @v_data_type_id varchar(50)


    Set @v_data_type_id = (
        SELECT  data_type_id 
        FROM OPENJSON (@JsonData, N'$') WITH (  data_type_id varchar(32) '$.dataTypeId') )

    set @json = @JsonData

    INSERT INTO TABLE1 (submission_id, data_set_id, data_type_id )
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@json, N'$') WITH (
        submission_id varchar(32) N'$.submissionId',
        data_set_id varchar(32) N'$.dataSetId',
        data_type_id varchar(50) N'$.dataTypeId'
      ) 

   if( @v_data_type_id = '1' )
   BEGIN 
     exec [dbo].[INSERT2] @json  
   End

   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
  THROW;
END CATCH
END
go
```

Comment: +1 for adding `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to the proc with the explict transaction. This is an often overlooked detail that can result in issues following a client timeout if omitted.

Comment: @David I've just edited my stored procedure and ran the procedures with data that would work with INSERT1 and *not* with INSERT2 but unfortunately it still submitted the data in INSERT1:


(1 row affected)

(0 rows affected)
OK

Comment: @codingnoob Yes, 1 row affected. And then rolled back. These messages mean nothing.

Comment: @GSerg What I want is, if 0 rows are inserted in the second stored procedure, then I want to roll back the first stored procedure. I've just looked inside TABLE1, and the records have indeed been inserted.

Comment: You have to THROW or RAISERROR in INSERT2 if zero rows are inserted.

Comment: Would replacing THROW with RAISERROR work? 

Also, I practically followed your code word for word, was this how it was meant to be written? I had to add 'TRANSACTION' at the end of ROLLBACK.

Comment: ROLLBACK or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are identical. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  Also either THROW or RAISERROR with a sufficient seveity (normally 16) will work.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In a nutshell, your solution works great but is there a way of bringing back a more meaningful error message as I always get the following: 

(0 rows affected)
Msg 6401, Level 16, State 1, Procedure INSERT_WORKFLOW_STATUS_EH2, Line 108 [Batch Start Line 0]
Cannot roll back THROW. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You need to open a transaction prior to the first `INSERT`, and then check the rowcount after the second stored procedure execution. Just make sure that the last operation in `[dbo].[INSERT2]` is the `INSERT` so it doesn't affect your `@@ROWCOUNT` value.

```
Create PROCEDURE INSERT1 (
        @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int
    declare @submission_id varchar(32)
    declare @dataset_id varchar(32)
    declare @json varchar(max) 
    DECLARE @v_data_type_id varchar(50)


    Set @v_data_type_id = (SELECT  data_type_id
        FROM OPENJSON (@JsonData, N'$')
      WITH (
        data_type_id varchar(32) '$.dataTypeId'))

    set @json = @JsonData

    BEGIN TRAN

        INSERT INTO TABLE1 (
        submission_id,
        data_set_id,
        data_type_id
        )
            SELECT *
            FROM OPENJSON (@json, N'$') WITH (
            submission_id varchar(32) N'$.submissionId',
            data_set_id varchar(32) N'$.dataSetId',
            data_type_id varchar(50) N'$.dataTypeId'
        ) 

        IF(( @v_data_type_id = '1'))
        BEGIN 

            exec [dbo].[INSERT2] @json  

            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRAN
                RETURN
            END
        END
    COMMIT TRAN
END
GO
```

In your `INSERT2` procedure, the last thing you are doing is selecting the error so you are ultimately affecting the affecting the `@@ROWCOUNT` value forcing it to always return 1. The insert statement needs to be the last operation in your INSERT2 stored procedure for it to return the proper value to the calling procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT2 (
    @Json_PMU1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int
    DECLARE @submission_id varchar(32)
    DECLARE @dataset_id varchar(32)

SELECT  @submission_id = submission_id,
        @dataset_id = data_set_id
from openjson(@Json_PMU1, N'$')
with (
submission_id varchar(32) N'$.submissionId',
data_set_id varchar(32) N'$.dataSetId'
)

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (
        name,
        contact_number,
        submission_id,
        data_set_id
)
select  Name as name,
        contactNumber as contact_number,
        @submission_id as submission_id, 
        @dataset_id as data_set_id
        
--into TABLE2

from openjson (@Json_PMU1, '$.data.Table2')
with (
    Name varchar(255) ,
    contactNumber char(11) 
)

END
```

Comment: I've just edited my stored procedure and ran the procedures with data that would work with INSERT1 and not with INSERT2 but unfortunately it still submitted the data in INSERT1: (1 row affected) (0 rows affected) OK

The procedure is updated all fine, but still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Both this answer and David Browne's answer should do exactly what you are trying to accomplish. It would be helpful to see your updated code.

Comment: I've updated the script in the question. I appreciate your patience. I'm quite new to this. :)

Comment: Everything in the INSERT1 strored procedure appears to be ok. Can you share the INSERT2 stored procedure code?

Comment: Updated my answer. I'll point out that this is just one way to approach this and it is fairly bare bones. David Browne's answer is a good pick too. He's gone ahead and showed you how to do it with proper error handling. Ultimately, whatever you choose, I think your main problems are within your INSERT2 implementation.

Comment: This worked! I enter a duplicate record into my table 2 and the message is as follows:
(1 row affected)
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure INSERT_PERSONNEL_TRACKER, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 0]
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'XPKPERSONNEL_TRACKER'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'SITE_TRACKING.PERSONNEL_TRACKER'. The duplicate key value is (GUID10, GUID10, N4, TEST, TEST, Works, East London, SK1451638298).
The statement has been terminated.

Despite saying (1 row affected), I check Table1 and the record was not inserted! Next step is to add a more meaningful error..